# How to create a delay while polling/scraping web site in a loop

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

*Please note I am not a professional programmer*

I have a small javascript for tampermonkey to work with the search form at some site. The task is the following - pass data to the search form, click "search" and then retrieve/parse results. The problem is that the site searches data at different speed - it could be 2-20+ seconds depending on situation. So far I used a code which waits fixed time before moving to the next query. Something like:

```
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 20000));
var SearchResult = await searching();
```

Searching() function here scans HTML for needed tags and returns "true" or "false" depending on result.

But now I would like to optimize script speed by reducing waiting (20s) timer. The logic here is to poll HTML every second after executing search query, scanning for tags, and in case of either true/false result move to the next query. Currently I don't get how to create a kind of "sleep" timer - to stop execution code inside my loop while page is polled for tags. Or may be I am completely wrong about "sleep" here and need another solution.

Here is a sample code I have used:

```
  // X here is number of queries to the site
  for (var i = 0; i < X; i++) {
      //executing a GET query to the site
      document.location = 'https://...';
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 20000));
      var SearchResult = await searching();

      if (SearchResult == true) {
          data[i] = parsing()
      }
      else if (SearchResult == false) {
          data[i] = '';
      }
}

function searching() {
    const el = document.getElementsByClassName('...')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('class');
    if (el == '...') {
        return true;}
    } else if (el == '...') {
        return false;}
}
```